# org.lwjgl.system.Library error

Tags: java, lwjgl, noclassdeffounderror

I set up LWJGL 3 in Eclipse, and it's giving me this error when I try to run the test code from https://www.lwjgl.org/guide:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.lwjgl.system.Library
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryAccess.<clinit>(MemoryAccess.java:22)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Pointer.<clinit>(Pointer.java:22)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.<clinit>(GLFW.java:594)
    at HelloWorld.run(HelloWorld.java:30)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:109)
```

I made sure that everything is set up correctly, and I just can't place my finger on the problem. What's wrong?

Comment: I'm also getting this error on command line (working in Eclipse) since I updated to _LWJGL 3.0.0b_. It worked in _3.0.0a_. Any news on that?

Answer (score 7):

You're missing the native libraries.

As described in this link https://www.lwjgl.org/guide you'll have to setup **java.library.path** to the native library location.

I downloaded the library and copied the HelloWorld code in the above link in HelloWorld.java inside the directory where I extracted the library.

So the contents inside looks like below

```
/HelloWorld.java
/build.txt
/doc
/jar
/native
/src.zip
```

I compiled and ran the HelloWorld.java as below

Compilation (Path separator on linux would be : so there it would be **-classpath jar/*:.**)

```
javac -classpath jar/*;. HelloWorld.java
```

Run

```
java -classpath jar/*;. -Djava.library.path=native HelloWorld
```

And this works.

Edit*

I downloaded the library from https://www.lwjgl.org/download (Download Release.)

In eclipse you can **add the native library to your path by simply including it on source path**. Like below:

[image: Right click on native>build path> use as source]

There's one more way using which native library can be added per Jar basis.

**Expand lwjgl.jar in build path > select native path > click on edit > click workspace > select native directory**.

See the images below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did that and now I'm getting an `ExceptionInInitializerError` from `glfwCreateWindow` on line 53...

Comment: Most likely it's Java version error, you probably have different version of java in Eclipse and on command line. I have made some edits to my answer to include how to include native files in Eclipse. This should work.

Comment: Strange, it seems that that's not the case.

Comment: In my case Eclipse is using the same JRE as the command line, but still I'm getting the _NoClassDefFoundError_.

Comment: Apparently the `-classpath` thing did the trick for me. Before I used the `-jar` param and had extracted the lwjgl.jar into my jar (on export). This seems not to work anymore since 3.0.0b. So for me it was not just about the natives.