# Eclipse isn't loading lwjgl properly

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, graphics, lwjgl

I'm trying to make a simple rendering program in Eclipse using LWJGL, but I'm having trouble getting the libraries to load. I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jdkq-aSFEA0&feature=youtu.be) and set up the build path as he instructed, but I'm still getting this error:

```
[LWJGL] Failed to load a library. Possible solutions:
    a) Set -Djava.library.path or -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath to the directory that contains the shared libraries.
    b) Add the JAR(s) containing the shared libraries to the classpath.
[LWJGL] Enable debug mode with -Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true for better diagnostics.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.lwjgl.system.MemoryAccess
    at org.lwjgl.system.Pointer.<clinit>(Pointer.java:22)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.<clinit>(GLFW.java:562)
    at Main.StartGE.main(StartGE.java:18)
```

The one difference between what he's doing and what I'm doing is that I'm using LWJGL 3 instead of 2. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.lwjgl.system.Library error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459196/org-lwjgl-system-library-error)

Comment: Seems like you have not linked the native files properly. Make sure that you've linked all the necessary native jar files.

Comment: For LWJGL 3 option b) seems to be the appropriate way: your Java build path must contain the for your operating system corresponding `lwjgl-*-natives-{linux|macos|windows}.jar` JARs. If this doesn't solve your problem, add a screenshot of your current Java class build to your question.

Comment: @SporreKing You were right! I had given Eclipse the wrong filepath to the natives.